# How to parametrize the intersection of two surfaces in 3D?

Tags: calculus

[image]

Having trouble with this problem. So far I this is what I've done:

$4y=z^2$

$z= \pm\sqrt{4t^2}$

and then sub again:

$x^2+y^2=z^2$

$x^2+t^2=\sqrt{4t^2}^2$

$x=\sqrt{3t^2}$

But like. Math software is telling me these are wrong. What's my problem here? Thank you!

Comment: $x^2+t^2=\sqrt{4t^2}^2$ ?

Comment: @LionHeart yea i was subbing in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the given parametrisation we have $z=t$ and hence from the second equation $y=\frac14 z^2=\frac14 t^2$ finally the first equation gives $x=\pm\sqrt{z^2-y^2}=\pm\sqrt{t^2-\left(\frac14 t^2\right)^2}=\pm\sqrt{t^2-\frac1{16}t^4}$.